# Melhor prática para chamar uma nova tela

Tags: android

Tenho uma `Activity` que contém uma `RecyclerView`, ao clicar sobre ela abre um `Dialog` com as informações do item selecionado.

E nessa `Activity` tem um `FloatingActionButton`, que quero que chame uma tela de cadastro. Qual a melhor prática de programação pra chamar essa tela?

- Chamar outro `Dialog` responsável pelo cadastro é uma boa?
- Crio uma `Activity` somente para ser responsável pelo cadastro?
- Chamo um `Fragment` mesmo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso irá depender de como será esse cadastro, se for algo simples como **nome**, **valor** e **data**, por exemplo, creio que o **Dialog** já resolve, agora se for algo mais extenso, um formulário grande, a **Activity** ou o **Fragment** seriam melhores, pois o **Dialog** vai ficar muito grande na tela, fica "feio" visualmente falando.

Entre a **Activity** e o **Fragment** você deve analisar algumas coisas, o contexto atual já tem onde encaixar esse **Fragment**?

Pois se você tiver que criar toda uma estrutura para tal, o melhor é poupar tempo e ir de **Activity**, mas se for por exemplo um tela com um **NavigationDrawer**, o **Fragment** já se encaixa mais fácil, porem com **Tabs** acho que não surtiria o mesmo efeito, então seria melhor outra **Activity**.